# I'm new to web development. Recently I keep getting in the console whether it is local or not, a GET to worldnaturenet.xyz

Tags: browser

I'm new to web development. Recently, every site/page I visit, local or web, I get the below error in the console. It feels that it is something I should be concerned about. Did I install something wrong? is it expected? what is it? I installed virtualBox vagrant, laravel, brackets with a single profile and no other add-ons, chrome and firefox on MacOs High Sierra.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 worldnaturenet.xyz/91a2556838a7c33eac284eea30bdcc29/validate-site.js?uid=51824x5680x&r=36()**

Comment: Please identify the programming language and developments tools being used so that the question can be tagged for the right topics

Comment: i installed vagrant and virtualBox and laravel plus brackets and browser on a fresh installation. if I visit anywebsite local or on the web I keep getting it for all and any visit.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 403 means forbidden. There must be some default security on some software you are using.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon again. Sorry guys for wasting your time and thank you for replying. I've had two browser add-ons which automatically installed when I signed in. One is doctoPDF i have no idea where I got that from, and speedtest and now it seems everything is back to normal. Thanks again for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using extension on your browser? We Have the same issue.
I'm using postman and i figured out that the extension I installed in my browser requiring a token try to disable it or login to the site

Comment: Yes thank you. Eventually, I found out it was postman. But didn't have the chance to update the post. Sorry.

Comment: well I'm happy to help. then can you give me and up vote

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, it was the postman plugin.